# Ionic with Android Emulator: Automatically send location?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, android-emulator, google-geolocation

I'm having an issue with my android emulator. When I close and re-open my app, the location is not sent automatically. I have to go into Extended Controls -> Location and click the 'Send' button for the Ionic Geolocation getCurrentPosition function to receive it.

When I boot up the android emulator and the app opens for the first time, this is not necessary. Any idea how to send the location automatically no matter what?

Comment: did you tried in mobile ? is this behaviour seen in mobile also? generally emulator doesn't perform the way you want to define them

Comment: It works fine on a mobile device for some reason. It's just android emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Generally for the Testing of Plugins we need to verify in the real device, but as your original question about using it in Emulators, for this to work out ,

1. Try to clear the cordova Cache ( if you are using Visual Studio , you can do it like  **Tools->Options**  )
2. Try to add watchPosition function with `enableHighAccuracy : true`

> ```
> navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { 
>     timeout:40000,
>     enableHighAccuracy: true 
> });
> ```

**Update :**

After a quick googling , found [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only) link , It states that  :

> Starting with Chrome 50, Chrome no longer supports obtaining the
>   user's location using the HTML5 Geolocation API from pages delivered
>   by non-secure connections. This means that the page that's making the
>   Geolocation API call must be served from a secure context such as
>   HTTPS.

A possible solution can be like :

By adding appropriate permissions on Android platform, open your project, search for `AndroidManifest.xml` and add these lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

For more Info Read [this](http://www.gajotres.net/using-cordova-geoloacation-api-with-google-maps-in-ionic-framework/) article and [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/geolocation-is-not-working-on-android/81152/8) thread

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I've been battling with this issue for a while and it seems to be something that none of those solutions could remedy. The work-around will suffice for now.

Comment: I have to go into Extended Controls -> Location and click the 'Send' button for the Ionic Geolocation getCurrentPosition function to receive it.